# c# cannot extract element with xsd:schemaLocation attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Please have a look at the following lines of XML codes. My goal is to extract the values in the `interactor` element:

```
<HPRD3r xmlns="org:hprd:dtd:hprd3r">
  <interactions>
    <entrySet xsi:schemaLocation="net:sf:psidev:mi http://psidev.sourceforge.net/mi/rel25/src/MIF25.xsd">
       <interactionList>
          <interactor>
```

For simplicity, let's assume `interactions` is a direct child of `root`.
Set the namespace as follows,

```
XNamespace ns = "org:hprd:dtd:hprd3r";
```

The following always returns `null` although "entrySet" is present:

```
root.Element(ns+"interactions").Element(ns+"entrySet");
```

On the other hand,

```
root.Descendants(ns+"interactor");
```

does not return `null` but gives a count of zero even if there are more than one `interactor` elements in the file.

Seems like the problem is the attribute `xsi:schemaLocation` in `entrySet`. Would someone explain to me please the reasons behind the problems above and how to fix them.
Thanks

Comment: I do it the easy way : root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "interactor").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Thank you, it did the job. I am still puzzled by why my approach did not work though. Any idea?

Comment: Get the default namespace of "interactor".  That will give you a clue.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the pasted document though, which may differ from the real document. The document above does not define any new namespace for `entrySet` and its descendants. `xsi:schemaLocation` alone does not add any default namespace binding. If in the real document, there is `xmlns="net:sf:psidev:mi"` inside the `entrySet` tag, then indeed you need to use the appropriate namespace and not the one stored in `ns`.

Comment: Thank you both. "interactor" does have another default namespace, I completely missed the xmlns inside  the entrySet tag. Lesson learned!